# can someone tell me why my Font family is not working and it shows default in server

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, vite

Here is tailwind config used in the project

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: ["./index.html", "./src/**/*.{js,jsx}"],
  mode: "jit",
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        Bitter: ["Bitter", "serif"],
    
      },
      
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

here is index.css file

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bitter:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800&display=swap');
```

here is the jsx file i wanted to change the font however the font just wont load and insted shows the default ui-sans

```
import React from 'react'
import { styles } from '../../styles/styels'
import Navbar from '../layout/Navbar.jsx'

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <div className={`${styles.boxWidth} flex justify-between  text-slate-50 m-auto align-middle items-center `}>
      <div className='font-Bitter'>
<h3 >Jonathan Spectre</h3>
</div>
</div> 
    </div>
  )
}

export default Header
```